# How do I get the window jelly effect?

Tags: compiz, configuration, animations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make my windows “wavy”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88860/how-do-i-make-my-windows-wavy)

I had Ubuntu before and there was an awesome option that allowed me to get a window "jelly" effect, however after reinstalling Ubuntu 6 months later I find that the system settings is less comprehensive and lacks my favorite "jelly" option. Any way to get it back?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/88860/18612

Answer (score 2):

You’ll want to enable “Wobbly windows” plugin in the CompizConfig Settings Manager. If you don’t have it installed, run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` or search for it in the Software Center.

- Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable wobbly windows but don't want to take the risks involved with using CCSM, you can also set this option using Ubuntu Tweak, under **Tweaks > Compiz Settings > Desktop Effects**:

[image: Location of wobbly windows setting in Ubuntu Tweak]

See [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75454/18612) for installation instructions.

Comment: Just to note - the only reason to state U-T is 'safer' then ccsm is it limits access to plugins. Otherwise it's no different - the desktop may flash/refresh after enabling a plugin. Additionally, given the default of 2X2 Ws's, U-T's "Enable workspace switching.." is done incorrectly & of little value. *if a user had previously set Desktop based viewport switching using the more useful 'prev/next' then U-T will actually go ahead set create a conflict without warning or option. (The bulk of the issues in 11.04/11.10 where the result of poor Ubuntu dev decisions, not ccsm itself